# Recursive call to find the sub lists of a list returns empty

Tags: list, scala, recursion

```
def find(list: List[(Char,Int)]):  List[(Char,Int)] = {
  list match {
    case List() => List()
    case (z,y):: xs => ((for(i <- 1 to y) yield (z,i)).toList ::: find(xs).toList)
  }  

find(List(('a',5),('b',3))) // will return nothing at all
```

I simply cannot understand why such a function will return empty for the given arguments. It does not have arguments which are empty so what could be the problem here?

This might be a very easy question but I really need a fresh pair of eyes to help me debug this as I simply am not able to spot the silly mistake I made

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function appears to work properly for me as it returns this:

```
List((a,1), (a,2), (a,3), (a,4), (a,5), (b,1), (b,2), (b,3))
```

I did notice in the code you provided you're missing a closing bracket on your `find` function, it should look like this:

```
  def find(list: List[(Char, Int)]): List[(Char, Int)] = {
    list match {
      case List() => List()
      case (z, y) :: xs => (for (i <- 1 to y) yield (z, i)).toList ::: find(xs)
    }
  }
```

Comment: Calling `toList` on `find(xs)` seems not needed, since `find` returns a `List` already?

Comment: @Noah Looks like I defined it in the worksheet and forgot to actually call it. The return that I saw was the return of the function. That's what I get if I use worksheets. No, you are not allowed to laugh